# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables warning

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

My codes for the prevention of SQL injection isn't working. Can anyone help me?

I'm receiving this warning: 
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables.

Thanks.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'Muproj');    
$query="INSERT INTO tblmember VALUES (':id', ':uname' , ':passwrd' , ':name' , ':surname' ,':0' )";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param(':id', $newid);
$stmt->bind_param(':uname', $C_uname);
$stmt->bind_param(':passwrd', $C_passwrd);
$stmt->bind_param(':name', $C_name);
$stmt->bind_param( ':surname', $C_surname);
$stmt->bind_param(':0', '0');
$stmt->execute();
$result=mysql_query($stmt);
```

Comment: You sure that parameter can be an integer?

Comment: You don't need to do `$stmt->bind_param(':0', '0');`. If you are hard coding 0 into the query then just write it into the query, it is hard coded and not a injection vulnerability.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, David. Looks suspect.

Comment: I'm actually receiving the mysqli_stmt::bind_param() warning for all the other bind_param codes.

Comment: Still, have you tried @ColSouth solution?

Comment: Yes! And also have this last warning for the  mysql_query:   Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Comment: You need to use `$result=mysql_query($query);` not `$stmt`.

Comment: When I do so, values are stores as ":id  :uname :passwrd  :name  :surname  0 "  in my database.

Comment: RIght, I didn't see that but you are using `mysql_query` when you are **in fact** using `mysqli`. Choose one of both (there is only one right answer here).

Comment: Yes, It did solve the warning on  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(). I've choosed mysql. But now I have this fatal error::   Fatal error: Class 'mysql' not found in .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you appear to be mixing PDO syntax with MySQLi syntax.

Please read up on http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

I do not use PDO myself much, but I do use MySQLi, so your references as `:something` are PDO declarations, but the SQL functions you use are MySQLi.

With a MySQLi `bind_param` function you need to add all the data into an array-like row (it may actually be an array), but preceeded by a declaration of types, as in **S**tring, **i**nteger, **D**ouble and **B**lob.

I have rewritten your code in the MySQLi form:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'Muproj');    
$query="INSERT INTO tblmember VALUES (?, ? , ? , ? , ? ,? )";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("issssi", $newid, $C_uname, $C_passwrd, $C_name, $C_surname, $zero)
$stmt->execute();
//$result=mysqli_query($stmt);
```

You need to do some serious research as to the differences of approach and formatting and functionality between MySQLi and PDO. Also be careful to maintain ALL your MySQL as MySQLi , as for example your `$result` was using the deprectated MySQL query statement.

PS: I would also suggest for clarity and forward compatibility that your `INSERT` statement in the SQL reads as:

```
 INSERT INTO table_name (column_names1, column_name2, column_names3, ...) VALUES (?,?,?, ...)
```

So you and the SQL can clearly see which values are plugged into which columns.